# iOS UI Not Updating

Tags: ios

I am using `Firebase` `Firestore` listeners and am updating 2 `tabBarItem` badges after fetching.

The badges were updating fine and appeared on the UI until I added a fourth listener, all of which I need. So in total I have 4 `asynchronous` listeners.

As I've put breakpoints, each listener is working correctly and fetching the right data, and at the point of setting the `badgeValue`, I see the correct count assigned that was a result of the fetch.

However, the UI either entirely doesn't update and show the `badgeValue` or inconsistently does.

Is this a memory issue with all the listeners firing off? Any thoughts on what I could possibly implement as a workaround? I've already tried things like `DispatchQueue.main.async`, and even delaying it, but all have shown inconsistent results.

Any help would be appreciated..

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling the app of whichever device you are testing it on.  It may be a firebase caching issue.

Comment: i don't think it's a caching issue, the correct badge values are being fetched every time it's just the UI not updating. i was able to solve it just now though. i basically fired off the listeners sequentially in each completion handler so they run one at a time.

Comment: Must check you firebase listener. and compare its value with database. May be its called twice.